# Adding disks to encrypted filesystem

Tags: partitioning, mount, encryption

I have a bit of a painful situation on a server of mine: It's a fullsidk encrypted system with three disks (2x 1000, 1x 500GB). However, I messed up setup quite a bit: Only one disk is used, and the biggest partition (950 GB) is mounted as /home. Now,I would need t 1) shrink the /home partition and mount it somwhere else, along with the other two disks. They would also need to be encrypted (either as part of the already existing fullsik encrpted system setup or separately).
Would greatly appreciate some help.

Edit: I'm using Debian 11 (just saw that this forum is Ubuntu only,sorry... I hope that's okay, the difference should be minimal, I think).
The fulldisk encryption is setup via the "Guided - Use entire disk and set up encrypted LVM" option during OS installation.

Comment: Could you [edit] your question to include: (0) the version of Ubuntu you're using (1) how the encrypted partition was set up. Depending on a couple of factors, adding the additional drives to the encrypted partition may not be a complete pain, but it depends a great deal on how the system is currently configured 

Comment: @matigo alright, is that enough information?

Comment: I have some good news and some bad news. First the bad news: Debian is off-topic here, as there's enough difference between raw Debian and stock Ubuntu to make topics like this non-transferrable. That said, the good news is that the friendly people at [the Debian User Forums](https://forums.debian.net/viewforum.php?f=10) should be able to answer your question accurately 

Comment: Alright, sory and thanks, will check out :) @matigo . Should I delete the post?

Comment: You can delete the post if you'd like. Otherwise the community will take care of it. Mind you, you're always welcome to ask questions here in the future if you start using Ubuntu 